# Swift 3 CollectionView or UITableView with fixed left column

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am using Swift 3.  I am currently using a UITableView to display a list of items - specifically a list of athlete results from a race and it has about 10 columns (e.g swim time, bike time, run time, place).  I am currently using a UITableView and it works OK, but I am finding it difficult/not possible to do what I want.  I found a few other solutions out here that are similar but they are using HTML/Web front ends vs swift 3 / native iOS.

I would like fixed width columns, and column headers.  I want to be able to scroll left and right and up and down.  I want the far left column to be *fixed*.  This is the column with the athlete name.  I want all the other columns to scroll left and right while this remains fixed.

I use an app called PowerSchool for my kids' school that illustrates the concept perfectly.  Attached are two screen shots with names and grades brushed out.

[Scroll View One](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bXLa4.png)

[Scroll View Two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHsOJ.png)

I am thinking that UITableView will not do this and I need to use UICollectionView or something else.

Any info to help me get started on this would be greatly appreciated.  I plan to make this work on iPad and iPhone in both portrait and landscape.

Answer (score 0):

Hi for this you need to two components.

- Either a `UIScrollView` with a `UITableView`
- or `UITableViewCell` inside a `UICollectionView`
- or a `UICollectionView` inside a `UICollectionView`

This can be achieved by mixing two components or you can use some sort of library:

https://github.com/fullc0de/HKKScrollableGridView
https://github.com/kanaishinichi/TAXHeaderSheet